# Прием сокета несколькими девайсов. Ява

Tags: java, android, сокет

Написал сервер Сокет на ява. Просто отпрвавляет рандомнае число при каждой итерации. Все окей работает но подключения два и несколька клиента сразу не получается.Отправляет сообщения лишь первому клиетну второй же извещает о подкючении но ничего сервер ему не посылает. 
Вот код Сервера:

```
public class JavaServer extends javax.swing.JFrame {

public JavaServer() {
    initComponents();
}


private void initComponents() {

    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    label1 = new java.awt.Label();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    label1.setText("Server");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
    jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
    jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(156, 156, 156)
            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 116, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(138, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(96, 96, 96)
            .addComponent(label1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 37, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(199, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
    );

    pack();
}// </editor-fold>                        

private static ServerSocket mySock;
private static Socket s;
private static BufferedReader br;
private static InputStreamReader in;
private static String msg = "hello I am Server";
private static PrintWriter pr;



public static void main(String args[]) {

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new JavaServer().setVisible(true);        
        }
    });

    try {



            mySock = new ServerSocket(5000);
            System.out.println("start\\n");
            while(true){
//                in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
//                br = new BufferedReader(in);
//                msg = br.readLine();

//                System.out.println("client:".concat(msg));
                while(true){
                    s = mySock.accept();
                    new UserDiolog(s);
                }
            }



    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}


// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private java.awt.Label label1;
// End of variables declaration                   
}
```

а вот класс UserDiolog:

```
package javaserver;

public class UserDiolog {
private Socket socket;
UserDiolog(Socket s){
    socket = s;
    userLisnter();
}

private void userLisnter(){
            try {
        while(true){
            Random random = new Random();
            int num = random.nextInt(100);
            PrintWriter pr = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
            pr.println("hello I am Server".concat(String.valueOf(num)).concat("\\n"));
            pr.flush();
            System.out.println("send\\n");
            if(!socket.isConnected()){
                pr.close();
//                    in.close();
//                    br.close();
                socket.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaServer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
}
```

В изучении сокета навичок. Что я не так сделал?

Comment: Надо начинать новый поток для каждого клиента
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209712/how-can-i-handle-multiple-clients-connected-to-a-server-using-sockets

Comment: @Likhanov а в ява AsyncTask нету?

Comment: Думаю нет. AsyncTask из пакета android.os.*

Comment: @Likhanov запустил в новом потоке все окей. Спасибо боьшое. Еще один маленький вопрос я запускаю поток прямь в его конструкторе . IDE его подсвечивает. Ничего же такого нету в запуске потока в конструкторе класса?

Comment: Хорошей практикой будет унаследоваться от `Thread` в `UserDiolog`, а сам `UserDialog` запускать как отдельный поток. Что-то вроде 
`public class UserDialog extends Thread` и `new UserDialog().start()`;

Comment: Когда пишут или говорят **ява** - рука так и тянется к револьверу...

Comment: @lampa  да я так и сдеалал. Все работает

Comment: @Barmaley кому как